Eforms Signature Field don't really work
I've tried adding signature fields with eforms with
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{eforms}
\begin{document}
df\sigField{My signature}{5cm}{3cm}
\end{document}

This creates a signature field, which I can sign with okular. But it doesn't show any visible signature information. Even adding a new signature field with okular while eforms is imported(not even used) makes signature field information invisible?
How do I make signature information visible while using eforms.

This is How it should look, and looks with PDFs without eforms

This is how it looks with eforms.
I've tried using lualatex an xelatex both don't work

works ok in acrobat reader, the signature is visible. I don't have okular to test. You could try \kvsetkeys{Form}{NeedAppearances=false}. That is the only setting I can think of they has global effect. Or provide a small, unsigned PDF made with okular so that one can check how they insert a signature field.

Thank you this works
